# How do I get emacs cider (clojure mode) to use my test environment variables when running tests?

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, cider

I've set up separate `database-url` for development and test environments, and this works nicely when running my webapp in the REPL and from the `lein test` on the command line. Here's my `profiles.clj`:

```
{:profiles/dev  {:env {:database-url "wiki"}}
 :profiles/test {:env {:database-url "wiki-test"}}}
```

And evidence of the right database instance being hit (I'm using CouchDB):

```
;; Running the site from the REPL:
[info] [<0.12149.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - GET /wiki/home-page 200
[info] [<0.10353.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - GET /wiki/about 200

;; Running lein test:
[info] [<0.12026.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - GET /wiki-test/welcome 404
[error] [<0.12933.0>] Could not open file /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb/wiki-test.c
```

However, when I run tests via Cider in Emacs it uses the dev environment and therefore the wrong database instance.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you try using `with-redefs` for that.

Something like this:

```
(with-redefs [db (get-my-test-db)]
  (run-my-tests)
```

Where `db` is the symbol to which you bind your db handle in your tests.

This article should be helpful:
[Isolating External Dependencies in Clojure](http://blog.josephwilk.net/clojure/isolating-external-dependencies-in-clojure.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think I can see how that would work, but it wouldn't use the test environment right? Maybe an alternative approach is to get Cider to use the test environment by default?

Comment: This worked. I put the function call `with-redefs` into a fixture so that it's called for every test.